# xlsxwriter conditional formatting by formula criteria

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I want to apply format to cells in a column. The row indexes are 5,7,8,9,10,11 and 13.

The code I am using is the following:

```
 worksheet.conditional_format("C4:C14", {'type'    :  'formula',
                                           'criteria': '=ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(),{5,7,8,9,10,11,13},0))=TRUE',
                                           'format'  :   format_white})
```

The result is no Excel file is generated.

The formula `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(),{5,7,8,9,10,11,13},0))=TRUE` works as I expected when I type it directly in Excel. I run the code above with a simpler formula `'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2)=0'` and it works, so I suspect the problem is in the criteria field.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for a formula to work in an XlsxWriter generated file it has to work in Excel.

In this case the conditional formula formula isn't valid in Excel:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(ROW(),{5,7,8,9,10,11,13},0))=TRUE
```

If you add it manually in Excel you get the following error/warning:

> "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or other array constants for Conditional Formatting criteria".

Comment: I see now @jmcnamara. I was testing the formula but not in the conditional formatting section. Thanks for your kind help.