# How to compare 2 strings in conditional_format in xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I want to compare 2 strings in conditional_format in xlsxwriter. For example, if cell W2 is not equal to neither "Bullish" nor "Bearish", the color of W2 changes to gray color.

My code is like this;

```
  gray_cell_format = workbook.add_format()
  gray_cell_format.set_font_color('#808080')
  worksheet.conditional_format(f'W2:W{size_dataframe}', {'type': 'formula',
                                                               'criteria': '=IF(ISNA(MATCH($W2, {"Bullish","Bearish"}, 0)),"YES","NO")',
                                                               'format': gray_cell_format})
```

However, it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try your `'=IF(...)` directly in `Excel` ?

Comment: [xlsxwriter conditional formatting by formula criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35338347/xlsxwriter-conditional-formatting-by-formula-criteria)